# Appended HTML from PHP via JQUERY breaking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, grid

I am using thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview and dropzone. When I upload a picture using dropzone, I want to append it to the thumbnail grid making a new one each time.

So far im using

```
   jQuery.ajax({            
        url: "get_imgs.php",
    type: "POST",          
    dataType: "HTML",
        success: function( data ) {
    jQuery('ul').append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, data ) {        
    alert ('Ajax request Failed.');    
    }
    });
```

to append this PHP:

```
    <?php
$img_dir = "uploads/";

 $images = scandir($img_dir);

$html = '';

$html .='';
foreach($images as $img)     {
    if($img === '.' || $img === '..') {continue;}         

        if (  (preg_match('/.jpg/',$img))  ||  (preg_match('/.gif/',$img)) ||                  (preg_match('/.tiff/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.png/',$img)) ) {                

         $html .='<li>
                <a href="#" data-largesrc="'.$img_dir.$img.'" data-title="Azuki bean"           data-description="Swiss chard pumpkin bunya nuts maize plantain aubergine napa cabbage soko coriander sweet pepper water spinach winter purslane shallot tigernut lentil beetroot.">
                    <img id="ten" src="'.$img_dir.$img.'" alt="img01" />
                </a>
            </li>';
        } else { continue; }    
}
 $html .='' ;

 echo $html ;
 //'.$img_dir.$img.'
 ?>
```

When I use it, the javascript to make the grid items expand only affects the ones in the original HTML and not the appended HTML.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Solved it! Instead of

```
jQuery.ajax({            
    url: "get_imgs.php",
type: "POST",          
dataType: "HTML",
    success: function( data ) {
jQuery('ul').append(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, data ) {        
alert ('Ajax request Failed.');    
}
});
```

I used:

```
      jQuery.ajax({            
        url: "get_imgs.php",
    type: "POST",          
    dataType: "HTML",
        success: function( data ) { 
   var $items = $(data).appendTo("#og-grid");
   Grid.addItems($items);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, data ) {        
    alert ('Ajax request Failed.');    
    }
    });
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: what is the plugin you're using? this one http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/ ? don't you need to let it know about the new images as well?

Comment: are you saying the new content is never appended?

Comment: The new content appends, but it doesn't expand properly. It displays but it has no properties like it's predecessor. Here's what's happening: http://dennisforhire.com/test/page3.html

Also, I've tried introducing the new images via Grid.addItems('Ul'); to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Also I know the images aren't to size, as I will resize them later, but they should still expand upon click, no?

Comment: Also using this if that helps [link](http://kvcodes.com/2013/12/get-all-images-from-a-directory-dynamically-php-jquery-ajax/)